# Получение данных из entry

Tags: python, tkinter

Написал код, нужно следующее:
вводят слова на английском в Entry(всего 7 раз) и нужно чтобы, при нажатии на кнопку выводилось самое длинное слово и его количество символов

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
root.title('Код')
root.geometry('800x330')
root["bg"] = "white"
label1=Label(text='1 слово')
label1.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
label2=Label(text='2 слово')
label2.grid(row=1, sticky=W)
label3=Label(text='3 слово')
label3.grid(row=2, sticky=W)
label4=Label(text='4 слово')
label4.grid(row=3, sticky=W)
label5=Label(text='5 слово')
label5.grid(row=4, sticky=W)
label6=Label(text='6 слово')
label6.grid(row=5, sticky=W)
label7=Label(text='7 слово')
label7.grid(row=6, sticky=W)
Entry1=Entry(width=15, font='Arial 12')
Entry2=Entry(width=15, font='Arial 12')
Entry3=Entry(width=15, font='Arial 12')
Entry4=Entry(width=15, font='Arial 12')
Entry5=Entry(width=15, font='Arial 12')
Entry6=Entry(width=15, font='Arial 12')
Entry7=Entry(width=15, font='Arial 12')
Entry1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E)
Entry2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E)
Entry3.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=E)
Entry4.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=E)
Entry5.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=E)
Entry6.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=E)
Entry7.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=E)


but=Button(text='Посчитать')
but=Button(text='Посчитать')
but.grid(row=8, column=5, sticky=E)
but.grid(row=8, column=5, sticky=E)
but1=Button(text='Закрыть')
but1=Button(text='Закрыть', command=root.destroy)
but1.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=E)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Разве нельзя обойтись с одним **Entry**? Или по условию надо чтоб прям 7 **Entry** было?

Comment: Нужно просто, чтобы вводилось 7 слов, а сколько Entry не имеет значения. Главное чтобы вывелось самое длинное слово и кол-во символов. И я не знаю как это сделать

Answer (score 1):

Для получения значения у `Entry` есть метод `get()`. Соответственно, просто пишется функция которая в цикле проходится по значениям всех Entry и вычисляет всё, что требуется. И эта функция вешается на кнопку.
Ну и для обработки однотипных элементов давно придуманы циклы и списки.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def btnCalc():
    max_word = ""
    max_len = 0
    for entry in entries:
        word = entry.get()
        if len(word) > max_len:
            max_word = word
            max_len = len(word)
    messagebox.showinfo("Результат", f"Самое длинное слово: '{max_word}'\nЕго длина: {max_len}")    
        
root=Tk()
root.title('Код')
root.geometry('800x330')
root["bg"] = "white"

entries = []
for i in range(7):
    Label(text=f'{i} слово').grid(row=i, sticky=W)
    entries.append(Entry(width=15, font='Arial 12'))
    entries[-1].grid(row=i, column=1, sticky=E)

but=Button(text='Посчитать', command=btnCalc)
but.grid(row=8, column=5, sticky=E)
but1=Button(text='Закрыть', command=root.destroy)
but1.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky=E)
root.mainloop()
```

Или та же функция, только записанная в более короткой форме:

```
def btnCalc():
    word = sorted((entry.get() for entry in entries), key = len)[-1]
    messagebox.showinfo("Результат", f"Самое длинное слово: '{word}'\nЕго длина: {len(word)}")
```